# In ETAS INCA, what classes correspond to each type of database item?

Tags: .net, calibration

[ETAS INCA](http://www.etas.com/en/products/inca_software_products.php) is the workhorse for many powertrain calibration engineers in the automotive industry--it's as essential to a calibration engineer as a good text editor or version control system is to a general-purpose software developer.  But its API documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Does anyone have a guide that shows how the database entities in the INCA GUI map to classes in the INCA COM/.NET API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The INCA API is structured to resemble the concepts that users are familiar with when they interact with INCA using the GUI.  Broadly speaking, you can do *most* of your GUI tasks programmatically through code.  That being said, the connection is not always clear in the INCA documentation.

The INCA API groups classes under two namespaces:

## de.etas.cebra.toolAPI.Common

Classes in this namespace encapsulate experiment-related tasks, such as reading measurements and setting calibration values.  You will see these objects "in action" when you are viewing an open experiment.  This is a pretty extensive namespace, so I will save it for a future post.

## de.etas.cebra.toolAPI.Inca

Classes in this namespace encapsulate INCA database tasks, such as copying or renaming items.  You will see these objects "in action" from the main INCA database window.

To follow along at home, fire up INCA, and then open the default "DB" demo database.  The screen shots below are from INCA 7, but for the images below, I have confirmed that the underlying API is nearly identical going back to INCA 5.4.

[image: INCA 7 Main window]

### The Database Objects Pane

[image: INCA 7 Database Objects Pane]

**Folders** like "USER A," "Demo," and "Measure Catalog," are represented by the **IncaFolder** class.

**Experiments** like "demo configuration 1" and "demo configuration 2" are represented by the **ExperimentEnvironment** class.

**ECU-Projects** like "Demo03" are represented by the **Asap2Project** class.

**ECU Documentation** does not appear to be covered in this namespace.  I will edit my answer if I learn otherwise.

**Workspaces** like "Workspace" are represented by the **HardwareConfiguration** class.

### ECU-Project elements

[image: INCA 7 Datasets pane]

When you click on an ECU-Project, the contents appear in the Datasets pane.  An ECU-Project only contains two classes, as shown below.

**Folders** are represented by the **Asap2ProjectFolder** class.

**Datasets** are represented by the **Dataset** class.

To access the other ASAP2 elements of a DataSet and ECU-Project, call the **Asap2Project.Asap2ModuleForDataSet()** method.