# In ETAS INCA, how can I extract specific calibration values by accessing the COM-API via VBA?

Tags: vba, api, calibration

I'm trying to construct a VBA script that opens INCA and extracts specific calibration values.

To start, I found a Youtube video by ETAS (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQAvE0UT5xk), and I copied the code from there:

```
Private Function inca_com_api() As Variant

Dim Inca As Object
Dim DB As Object
Dim DBname As String
Dim devices() As Variant
Dim calValue As Variant

Set Inca = CreateObject("inca.inca")
Set DB = Inca.GetCurrentDataBase
DBname = DB.GetName

inca_com_api = DBname

Inca.DisconnectFromTool

End Function
```

The code opens INCA and runs as intended, returning the database name, but what I want is not the database name, but specific calibration values.

I was under the impression that I could just use the API functions listed in the User's Guide for INCA-MIP (https://www.etas.com/en/downloadcenter/18008.php), which is the INCA COM-API interface package for Matlab.
I don't have INCA-MIP, I just thought I could call those functions through VBA, by using the same function name or similar function names.

But when I try code like:

```
devices() = DB.IncaGetDevices
```

or

```
devices() = DB.GetDevices
```

or

```
devices() = Inca.IncaGetDevices
```

or

```
devices() = Inca.GetDevices
```

or the same variations of GetCalibrationValue, IncaGetCalibrationValue, I get:

Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I was planning to use IncaGetDevices to show me a device name, which I could then use as an input argument for IncaGetCalibrationValue, for each of my specific calibration names that I want returned.

Again, I don't have INCA-MIP, but I am wondering how I can return these calibration values using the VBA and the COM-API for INCA?

Also, I tried looking through the following posts for answers:

[In ETAS INCA, is there a way to quickly retrieve an item from an arbitrary path in an ASAP2Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214951/in-etas-inca-is-there-a-way-to-quickly-retrieve-an-item-from-an-arbitrary-path)

[In ETAS INCA, what classes correspond to each type of database item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932147/in-etas-inca-what-classes-correspond-to-each-type-of-database-item)

but I don't really know what they're talking about.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I know nothing about your library, but I suspect you could go in Tools / References and add a reference to it. Then you could explore what it has to offer from the Object Explorer (F2), on top of getting IntelliSense while you code.

Comment: oh shit, this Object Explorer thing just blew my mind.  Thx bromigo